# Aggregate data with date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table (#CategoryWeight) where weight and factor values are stored for each category with date ranges. I need to aggregate / simplify this data, when possible, so that consecutive data ranges are combined into a wide range for the same values of weight and factor.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CategoryWeight;
CREATE TABLE #CategoryWeight ( [CategoryId] bigint, [weight] float(8), [factor] float(8), [startYear] nvarchar(60), [endYear] nvarchar(60) )
INSERT INTO #CategoryWeight
VALUES
( 42, 1, 0, N'2009', N'2014' ), 
( 42, 1, 0, N'2009', N'2019' ), 
( 42, 1, 0, N'2015', N'2017' ), 
( 42, 1, 0, N'2018', N'2019' ), 
( 42, 1, 1, N'2020', N'9999' ),

( 40, 1, 0, N'2009', N'2014' ), 
( 40, 1, 0, N'2009', N'2017' ), 
( 40, 1, 0, N'2015', N'2017' ), 
( 40, 1, 0, N'2020', N'9999' ), 
( 40, 1, 1, N'2018', N'2019' ),

( 45, 1, 0, N'2009', N'2014' ), 
( 45, 0, 0, N'2015', N'2017' ), 
( 45, 1, 0, N'2020', N'9999' ), 
( 45, 0, 1, N'2018', N'2019' );'

CategoryID  weight  factor  startYear   endYear
42          1       0       2009        2014
42          1       0       2009        2019
42          1       0       2015        2017
42          1       0       2018        2019
42          1       1       2020        9999
40          1       0       2009        2014
40          1       0       2009        2017
40          1       0       2015        2017
40          1       0       2020        9999
40          1       1       2018        2019
45          1       0       2009        2014
45          0       0       2015        2017
45          1       0       2020        9999
45          0       1       2018        2019
```

Expected result:

```
CategoryID  weight  factor  startYear   endYear
42          1       0       2009        2019
42          1       1       2020        9999
40          1       0       2009        2017
40          1       1       2018        2019
40          1       0       2020        9999
45          1       0       2009        2014
45          0       0       2015        2017
45          0       1       2018        2019
45          1       0       2020        9999
```

Comment: Nick, thank you for editing my post.

Comment: which SQL engine you are using?

Comment: @fomkatya . . . Based on the syntax of the code in the question, I added the SQL Server tag.  You should tag questions with the database that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overlapping time periods.  That makes any assumption about the data troublesome -- because the same year *could* have different values on different rows (nothing in your question precludes this).

Hence, the approach that I recommend is to expand out the data and then recombine it into chunks where the values are the same.  The following uses a recursive CTE to expand the data and then a gaps-and-islands trick to recombine it:

```
with cte as (
      select categoryid, weight, factor,
             convert(int, startyear) as year, convert(int, endyear) as endyear
      from categoryweight
      union all
      select categoryid, weight, factor,
             year + 1, endyear
      from cte
      where year < endyear
     )
select categoryid, weight, factor, min(year), max(year)
from (select categoryid, weight, factor, year,
             row_number() over (partition by categoryid, weight, factor order by year) as seqnum
      from (select distinct categoryid, weight, factor, year from cte) cte
     ) cte
group by categoryid, weight, factor, (year - seqnum)
order by categoryid, min(year)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60340e28e80659e2ffc8a8be0a166363) is a db<>fiddle.

I notice a few things about your data.

- You are using `float` for some of the values.  This is *very* dangerous, because two values might look the same but really differ by a very small amount.  Use the `decimal`/`numeric` type instead, so what-you-see-is-what-you-get.
- The `year` values are strings, when they should be integers.  Use the proper data types!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, SQL Server or PostgreSQL then you can do something like following using window function.

```
select
    distinct CategoryID, 
    weight, 
    factor,
    min(startYear) over (partition by CategoryID, weight, factor) as startYear,
    max(endYear) over (partition by CategoryID, weight, factor) as endYear
from categoryWeight
order by
    CategoryID
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is what I had as my solution before. But it generates overlapping date ranges, so it does not resolve my issue.